# assembly word count in string

Tags: assembly

Writing a program that counts words in the string (user input). I got char count so far but still can't make it to count words. (Searched all internet for exact answer, but couldn't find, Even Russian sites) If anyone will help I will very appreciate. (Using Kip Urvine library, it's a must). 
Will be enought if someone will show the direction where to dig!

Here is the CODE:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
Get_frequencies PROTO, pString:PTR BYTE, ; points to string
pTable : PTR DWORD; points to frequency table
.data

freqTable DWORD 256 DUP(0)

; aString BYTE 1, 2, "Hello World.", 0

aString BYTE 80 DUP(0), 0
str1 BYTE "*** CALCULATION PROGRAMM   ***",
0dh, 0ah, 0dh, 0ah,
"Enter Your Message: ", 0
.code
main PROC
call Clrscr
mov edx, OFFSET str1
call WriteString
mov ecx, SIZEOF aString - 1
mov edx, OFFSET aString
call ReadString
INVOKE Get_frequencies, ADDR aString, ADDR freqTable
call DisplayTable
exit
main ENDP
Get_frequencies PROC,
pString:PTR BYTE, ; points to string
pTable : PTR DWORD; points to frequencey table
mov esi, pString
mov edi, pTable
cld; clear Direction flag(forward)
L1: mov eax, 0; clear upper bits of EAX
lodsb; AL = [ESI], inc ESI
cmp al, 0; end of string ?
je Exit_proc; yes: exit
shl eax, 2; multiply by 4
inc DWORD PTR[edi + eax]; inc table[AL]
jmp L1; repeat loop
Exit_proc :
ret
Get_frequencies ENDP
DisplayTable PROC
;
.data
colonStr BYTE ": ", 0
.code
call Crlf
mov ecx, LENGTHOF freqTable; entries to show
mov esi, OFFSET freqTable
mov ebx, 0; index counter
L1 : mov eax, [esi]; get frequency count
cmp eax, 0; count = 0 ?
jna L2; if so, skip to next entry
mov eax, ebx; display the index
call WriteChar
mov edx, OFFSET colonStr; display ": "
call WriteString
mov eax, [esi]; show frequency count
call WriteDec
call Crlf
L2 : add esi, TYPE freqTable; point to next table entry
inc ebx; increment index
loop L1

call Crlf
ret
DisplayTable ENDP
END main
```

THE OUTPUT is: 
COUNTING JUST CHARACTERS.

Comment: Your code is for counting appearances of characters in a string, this is a complete different thing than what you want ;) you need something that iterates thru all characters in your string, and counts whenever you "enter" a word, and then finding the end of that word. repeated 'til your string ends

Comment: Do you understand how the input text is encoded/stored in computer memory? How to find borders of words? Then write the detection... then just count how many times it was triggered... then use all kind of weird inputs to validate it. Throw it away, and design new one, which will work... done.

Comment: At least I know that this one is not working, Thank you guys. Appreciate.